# CJuiDialog page redirect, Yii web application

Tags: php, modal-dialog, yii

I am trying to implement a password reset page.  After the password is reset i want it to display a dialog saying the email was sent then redirect the page to the login screen the the dialog is closed.

Here is what have for the dialog and redirect:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Email Notification',
                'autoOpen'=>true,
             ),
        ));

 "Email has been sent!";

 $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

 $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/login'));
```

When the user hits submit to start the password reset function it displays this error page:

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Library/WebServer/Documents/yii/framework/zii/widgets/jui/CJuiDialog.php:73)

Does anyone know how to fix this?  also is there a way to add an ok button on the dialog so when they click ok then it redirects to the login screen?

Comment: Shouldn't the redirect be in the controller file?  This looks like a view.

Comment: this is in the controller file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding a button to the dialog.  When the button is pressed, it uses javascript to redirect to my login page.